# How to give permision to a user in certificate PKCS12 with powershell ? without openssl if possible

Tags: powershell, ssl-certificate

I have a code, that i got from here which is/was quite useful, the problem is, it only works for low RSA certificates, the situation is, i need to give permission to a user in that certificate PKCS12, i have a cheap way of doing it because i know where the key will be put in :

```
try{

    $vReport = $Report.startname -replace '\.\\', "$($env:computername)\"
    $Rule = new-object -typename System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -Argumentlist $vReport, $Permission, Allow
    $Root = "c:\programdata\microsoft\crypto\Keys\"
    $Path = ls Cert:\LocalMachine\My\ | where {$_.thumbprint -like $Thumbprint}
    $Path | foreach {
                       $Privatekey = Get-ChildItem -Path $Root | Sort-Object -Descending LastWriteTime | select name -First 1 
                       $KeyPath = Join-Path -Path $Root -ChildPath $Privatekey.Name
                       if([io.file]::exists($KeyPath)){
                                                        $acl = get-acl -Path $KeyPath
                                                        $acl.AddAccessRule($Rule)
                                                        echo $KeyPath
                                                        set-acl -AclObject $acl -path $KeyPath   
                                                       }
                    }
} 

Catch{

       Write-Warning "An Exception was caught: $_" 

     }
}
```

It works but one of my co-worker asked me "imagine we are both in the same server and inserting 2 different certificates?",if he implement his certificate a few sec later, it's going to insert the user in the wrong private key.
After a lot of search i found that the certificate has subject key identifier that matches with the key in the registry, could that be a solution? If so how to get it? Because I've been trying endlessly ( within the scope of my knowledge).

**UPDATE** : Found that using the property $_.Extension.Privatekeyidentifier you get the key name in the registry. The other question i have is, how do i map them so it can go to the right folder to discover the key that is shared with the certificate?

Comment: Doesn't the name of the private key file contain a hash you can correlate with the cert?

Comment: that is the problem the only hash i can get is from the public the private is empty otherwise it would give me more properties such as : $_.privatekey.cspkeycontainerinfo.uniquekeycontainername <-- this contains the path to the registry and its name (if i'm not mistaken).
But in the certificate there's a subject key identifier that matches the key name in the registry, but i can't get ( and i don't know ) how i should proceed to find that property with powershell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after a lot of search and help from a colleague of mine, managed to get an answer that me and probably a lot more other people were looking for:

```
if ($null -eq $Certificate.PrivateKey) {
                
            Write-Verbose -Message "Checking Keys folder."
            $keyPath = $env:ProgramData + '\Microsoft\Crypto\Keys\'
                
            Write-Verbose -Message "Getting RSA private key path."
            $rsaKey = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.RSACertificateExtensions]::GetRSAPrivateKey($Certificate)
            $keyName = $rsaKey.Key.UniqueName
                
            Write-Verbose -Message "Combining path and private key"
            $KeyFullPath = $keyPath + $keyName

            Write-Verbose -Message "Testing if the path is true."
            if (Test-Path $keyFullPath) {                                                        
                    
                Write-Verbose -Message "Getting acl from the file located in that path."
                $acl = get-acl -Path $keyFullPath 
                                                    
                Write-Verbose -Message " Adding the rule to the respective file. "
                $acl.AddAccessRule($Rule)
                                                    
                Write-Verbose -Message "Outputing the file path."
                Write-Information $keyFullPath

                Write-Verbose -Message "Accepting the requested acl."
                set-acl -AclObject $acl -path $keyFullPath
            }
```

with this piece of code you will be able to find the private key of a PKCS12 certificate and give permission to a user.

Sorry for the late reply since i found this much earlier but while i was working on m project i forgot to post the discovery. i hope this is helpful in case of any doubt please tell me.